# Problem with stroke

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, path, stroke

I am creating a leaf from scratch in illustrator, I made the stroke a different color than the fill, and now I can see that the stroke is sort of distorted and is not properly lined up to the actual shape itself. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: It is hard to say what is going on with your drawing without more info or a screenshot- it could be that you have an "effect" applied to the path that is making it not adhere exactly to the path (roughen or zigzag maybe ?) a look at the appearance panel would be a good place to start- it seems unlikely that the distorted stroke has anything to do with your different colored fill

Comment: The Stroke appears to have a brush applied to it. Chances are it's the brush stroke causing the apparent misalignment. Change the setting to "Basic" and see if it aligns.

Answer (score 1):

As Scott mentioned you probably have a brush applied to the stroke for some reason. Open up the Brushes panel from the `Main Menu > Window > Brushes` and click the 'Basic' style as shown below.

[image]

Comment: I just now tried to change it back to basic, it's still showing the same appearance for some reason.

Comment: What happens if you just remove the stroke completely then ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have drawn a separate stroke shape which doesn't fit well enough. Remove it and insert a new to the base leaf shape or (or a copy of it, no fill). Use the width tool to get some variation.

If you have a copy of the leaf shape you can even split the curve with the Scissors to get individually adjustable stroke shapes.

An example:

[image]

1. My basic leaf shape with no stroke
2. An uniform stroke is inserted
3. The width tool is used to get some variation. The stroke is not a separate shape in this case.